# Symfony Passing Doctrine Paginator to a service

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine

I want to une the class Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator in a service in symfony, so the service return an instance for this class does not exist. with best practice shoud i pass the class directly or create a service who return an instance of this class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a service using [Factory Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to instantiate the Paginator class with required params (Query/QueryBuilder and fetchJoinCollection) and inject it into your class. Using this approach will help you to mock the Paginator object while unit testing your service.

Answer (score 1):

Create a private Service as parametre

```
services:
    your.service.name:
        class:  AppBundle\Services\YourClassName
        arguments:  ['@doctrine.services.paginator']

    doctrine.services.paginator:
      class: Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator
      public: false
```

Comment: But Paginator need constructor parametre